# Pickling doubly-decorated functions for Multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-decorators

I'm trying to write some boilerplate code to simplify a common workflow:
Given some function `f` that takes in arguments, and a list of these arguments, return a new function that creates the queues and processes, passes off work, and finally gathers the results from a queue into a list

I realize that this is quite similar to what `map` does, but this should be more flexible (although irrelevant for the MWE.

The issue is that pickling the decorated function does not work, even after I used `functools.wraps`.

When I tested by passing in the "queued" version of the function, rather than creating it within `process_wrapper`, the code ran without issue.  Thus, I think the issue is that the function `f` is being "double decorated", but I don't know how to address the issue.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.queues import Queue
from typing import Callable
from functools import wraps

def func_wrapper(f: Callable) -> Callable:
    @wraps(f)
    def q_f(q_in, q_out):
        while not q_in.empty():
            args = q_in.get()
            out = f(*args)
            q_out.put(out)
        return
    return q_f

def process_wrapper(f: Callable, num_process: int = 10) -> Callable:

    f = func_wrapper(f)
    @wraps(f)
    def ff(ls) -> list:
        manager = mp.Manager()
        q_in = manager.Queue()
        q_out = manager.Queue()

        [q_in.put(x) for x in ls]

        # queue_func = f

        processes = []
        for _ in range(num_process):
            p = mp.Process(target = f, args = (q_in, q_out))
            processes.append(p)
            p.start()

        for p in processes:
            p.join()

        output = []
        while not q_out.empty():
            output.append(q_out.get())

        return output
    return ff

if __name__ == "__main__":

    def f(x):
        print(x)
    f = process_wrapper(f)
        

    list_args = [(x,) for x in range(100)]

    f(list_args)
```

Comment: Can you paste your error output?  This code works for me.

Comment: `_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function f at 0x10db48670>: it's not the same object as __main__.f`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `multiprocess` rather than `multiprocessing` and it resolved the issues.  It has something to due with the limitations of `pickle` versus `dill` for serialization